# Linux/Unix run as kernel

Tags: c, linux, system

I'm interested in writing a program that runs as a kernel service. 
But first Am i right that if a program runs as kernel, does this override the permissions of super-users on an Linux/Unix system?

Comment: Programs cannot run in kernel space. They are confined to user space. You need a kernel module to run in kernel space. You can use ioctl calls, pipes etc. to communicate between a program in user space and a kernel module through a special file node in /dev/.

Comment: They can, if you've got KML patch installed. Or using ucLinux. :)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289938/execute-a-program-in-kernel-space-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to develop is called a "kernel module". And yes, there are no restrictions on what kernel module threads can do in the system, including breaking everything badly.

That's a good starting point to learn about those:

http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Surprisingly, it is possible to run "normal" applications in Linux kernel space, for some added (but minor) benefits. The mechanism is called "kernel mode linux" and is available as a patch:

http://www.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/kml/

But judging from your question, you may want to do the opposite: develop a kernel service which benefits from added protection available in user space. This is also supported by means of UIO subsystem (in the main kernel tree):

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12/Documentation/DocBook/uio-howto.tmpl